# I need an example of calling the same javascript function multiple times sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day

I have a call to the same function 9 times. Unfortunately it looks like it runs so fast that a couple of function dont finish or get called

```
             loadpaymentboxes('1t1', '1h1', p1t1, p1i1);
             loadpaymentboxes('1t2', '1h2', p1t2, p1i2);
             loadpaymentboxes('1t3', '1h3', p1t3, p1i3);

             loadpaymentboxes('2t1', '2h1', p2t1, p2i1);
             loadpaymentboxes('2t2', '2h2', p2t2, p2i2);
             loadpaymentboxes('2t3', '2h3', p2t3, p2i3);

             loadpaymentboxes('3t1', '3h1', p3t1, p3i1);
             loadpaymentboxes('3t2', '3h2', p3t2, p3i2);
             loadpaymentboxes('3t3', '3h3', p3t3, p3i3);
```

How do you chain these calls so that only after the the previous call has finished, it is allowed to run it again.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thanks, that article makes sense, I just don't understand the syntax of it in my example. Do you have time to give me a starting point? Cheers!

Comment: Is `loadpaymentboxes()` async?   If it's synchronous then it is already waiting until previous calls are done before starting the next one; if it's asynchronous (i.e. returns a Promise) you can chain them with `.then()`, but whether that makes sense or is necessary would depend on what the function is doing.  "it runs so fast that a couple of function dont finish or get called" is almost certainly not true; js doesn't just start skipping past lines of code because it's moving too fast.

Comment: The function does an ajax call to get the totals for a payment box. It performs the calculation then writes the payment to the html. It will populate most of the 9 boxes but for some reason randomly skips a couple, until I run it again.

Answer (score 2):

This code will execute the functions after one second

```js
var i = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if( i >= 9 ) {
    clearInterval( timer );
  }
  //YourFunction();
  console.log(i);
   i++;
}, 1000/*Change this time in milliseconds to modify the execution time between functions*/);
```

Comment: And if the call takes 1.1 second?